# Can`t call correctly function with sort in Python

Tags: python, list, function, sorting

So, I have a nested list, which I need to sort by value with using def. The problem is, that function, that sorts list with key, as another function isn`t called correctly. 
It repeats and repeats.

```
currencies=[['hryvna', '1 hryvna', '2005', '0.036'], ['dollar', '1 dollar', '2006', '1'], ['euro', '1 euro', '2007', '1.08'], ['Belarusian ruble', '1 Belarusian ruble', '2008', '0.39'], ['pound', '1 pound', '2009', '1.23']]
def atribute_choice():
    atribute=int(input("""Choose the atribute:
    1 - Currency name;
    2 - Currency denomination;
    3 - Currency year of release;
    4 - Currency rate to the dollar\n"""))
    atribute=atribute-1
    return atribute
def sorting(elem):
    return elem[atribute_choice()]
def currencies_sorting():
    currencies.sort(key=sorting)


currencies_sorting()
print (currencies)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it keeps asking for inputs is that you ask for input for each row in your 2D list.

If you want to ask it only once then modify your code as:

```
currencies = [['hryvna', '1 hryvna', '2005', '0.036'],
['dollar', '1 dollar', '2006', '1'],
['euro', '1 euro', '2007', '1.08'],
['Belarusian ruble', '1 Belarusian ruble', '2008', '0.39'],
['pound', '1 pound', '2009', '1.23']]

def atribute_choice():
    atribute = int(input("""Choose the atribute:
    1 - Currency name;
    2 - Currency denomination;
    3 - Currency year of release;
    4 - Currency rate to the dollar\n"""))
    atribute = atribute - 1
    return atribute

def sorting(elem):
    a = elem[attribute]
    return a

def currencies_sorting():
    currencies.sort(key=sorting)


attribute = atribute_choice()
currencies_sorting()
print(currencies)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
currencies=[['hryvna', '1 hryvna', '2005', '0.036'], ['dollar', '1 dollar', '2006', '1'], ['euro', '1 euro', '2007', '1.08'], ['Belarusian ruble', '1 Belarusian ruble', '2008', '0.39'], ['pound', '1 pound', '2009', '1.23']]
def atribute_choice():
    atribute=int(input("""Choose the atribute:
    1 - Currency name;
    2 - Currency denomination;
    3 - Currency year of release;
    4 - Currency rate to the dollar\n"""))
    atribute=atribute-1
    return atribute

def currencies_sorting():
    choice = atribute_choice()
    currencies.sort(key=lambda x: x[choice])


currencies_sorting()
print (currencies)
```

Also you can find more information about sorting [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting/)

Answer (score 0):

The `key` function is called for each element that is being sorted. You need to choose the attribute ahead of time, and then use that value in the key.

So you want to pass that value to `sorting`, but don't have it available at the place where `sorting` is called (internally, by the sort method). You need to "bind" it; we *could* do this elegantly with `functools.partial` from the standard library:

```
from functools import partial

def sorting(choice, elem):
    return elem[choice]

def currencies_sorting():
    attribute = attribute_choice()
    currencies.sort(key=partial(sorting, attribute))
```

But it turns out that we have an even more direct tool in the standard library for this problem:

```
from operator import itemgetter

def currencies_sorting():
    currencies.sort(key=itemgetter(attribute_choice()))
```

Or you can build it yourself using `lambda`, as shown in the other answer.